# "Как очарованный" и "так же / также"

Tags: слитно-раздельно, как

*Саша(,) как очарованный(,) смотрел на сидящую за соседним столом голубоглазую девушку, на вид лет тридцати, которая так же безотрывно глядела на него.*

Нужно ли обособлять "как очарованный"? И меня смущает это "так же" - на что оно ссылается? Если заменить на "тоже" или "также", лучше не становится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обособлять я бы не стал, поскольку оборот тесно связан со сказуемым.

*Так же безотрывно,* **как и он,** как я понимаю.

Comment: Спасибо. А почему оборот тесно связан? Можно же и без него обойтись. С "так же" непонятно... Может, запятыми выделить? "...так же, безотрывно, глядела..."

Comment: Артем, плюс от меня за правильное решение . Правда, объяснение у меня немного другое, но это ведь ничего.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Шарон! @Kirill: тесно связан он потому, что примыкает к нему и по смыслу относится к нему, характеризует, как Саша смотрел. Не надо обособлять в конце ничего! Девушка смотрела так же безотрывно, как и Саша, что непонятного-то? ;)

Comment: @Sharon, a Вы не могли бы написать здесь свое объяснение? И может, вариант с обособлением всё же возможен?

Comment: Могу дать короткий комментарий.  (1) Действительно, вариант с обособлением возможен, но для этого надо перестраивать структуру предложения.  А здесь оборот занимает позицию наречия/обстоятельства. Сравнить: Саша зачарованно смотрел...  (2)  "Так же" раздельно, так как  местоимение ТАК относится к наречию "безотрывно": так (же) безотрывно, как он.  Сравнить: также/тоже глядела на него.

Comment: @Sharon Все равно я сомневаюсь. Вот если бы было так: "Саша смотрел как очарованный...", то запятые не нужны. А в исходном варианте хочется выделить.

Comment: Понимаю, что хочется: оборот более распространенный и его удобнее обособлять (по сравнению с наречием).. Но не нужно этого делать.. Я для решения пользуюсь интонационным анализом и вижу, на какие части/синтагмы его надо делить при произношении.  А произносить  его нужно так: Саша как очарОванный / смотрел на сидящую за соседним столом голубоглазую дЕвушку/, на вид лет тридцати/... А вы предлагаете первую часть разделить еще на две части, а зачем? Так оно  у нас  вообще рассыплется ;)

Comment: Спасибо всем!..

Comment: @Sharon: так я тоже хотел сказать, что "так же" относится к "безотрывно"! Значит, на этом мы сходимся?

Comment: Да, на этом мы сходимся :) Что касается первой части вопроса,  то очень хорошо, что вы можете на слух определить правильное решение. А убедить в этом кого-либо достаточно сложно, вы сами видите. Мне кажется, что Kirill так до конца и не согласился со мной.  Дело в том, что при анализе мы должны рассматривать предложение как единое целое, а многие анализируют отдельные части как самостоятельные предложения.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, я согласился.

Comment: @Sharon: я, кстати, с самого начала тоже подумывал про наречную функцию "как зачарованный", просто не нашёл, как это хорошо аргументировать и каким наречием заменить для иллюстрации.

Comment: Все отлично, Артем, вы на правильном пути. Отвечайте чаще, приобретайте опыт, тогда  будете все хорошо аргументировать. Кстати, я учусь постоянно. Даже этот вопрос помог мне лучше строить аргументацию.  Особенно этому способствуют люди, которые умеют думать и задают дополнительные вопросы по еще неясной для них  тематике.

Answer (score 0):

как не нужно, запятые не нужны - одиночное причастие, а не причастный оборот, также - слитно. Глядела неудачное слово.  Саша очарованный/очаровано смотрел на сидящую за соседним столом голубоглазую девушку, на вид лет тридцати, которая также не отводила от него взгляда. И девушка 30 лет... я бы убрал возраст).

Или вообще так:

*Очарованный взгляд Саши вдруг оказался как бы прикован к сидящей за соседним столиком незнакомке. Девушка также с интересом рассматривала молодого человека и не спешила спрятать тайну своих сапфировых глаз в соседний карман городского переулка.*

Comment: Хорошее слово "глядела", зря вы.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Оно не "плохое", а неудачно здесь. Но смотря какая задача, оно более звонкое, резкое и грубоватое.

Comment: А почему закавычили?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой потому что плохих слов в русском языке не бывает.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я подумал просто, что смысл лечить фразу-урод, если там куча стилистических ошибок и недочетов, и получать в итоге урода-инвалида, если проще переписать, сделав по-новому.